# Autodesk Forge Three JS version to support ShapeBufferGeometry

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are currently trying to instantly draw 3D shapes in the autodesk viewer. We have managed this by injecting a javascript runtime to the underlying Three.JS engine.
For complex 3D shapes with for instance polygons with holes, triangulation is necessary. To support this, Three.js has added `ShapeBufferGeometry` on Oct 31, 2016, and is published with release 83 on december 2016.
If I get it right, current Forge viewer is built on Three.JS r71.
Are there any plans to update Forge with latest Three.JS? Or do you have any advise to create a work around for this, other than running the triangulation ourselves?

Comment: This is not really a programming question. You should reach out to Autodesk directly, since there's no way for outsiders to know what Autodesk's plans for the future are.

Comment: Autodesk directs all viewer support questions to StackOverflow these days, so this might be the only good channel to ask...

Comment: @Matt wow, you're right. They don't even have customer service contact information on their site! They offer a paid service that defers all its support to S.O.?

Comment: Autodesk Employees do spend a fair amount of time responding on SO- but I agree it still seems odd.

Comment: (Like Philippe, below)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the code for [ShapeBufferGeometry](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/geometries/ShapeGeometry.js) to your app. The base class `BufferGeometry` is supported by the Three.js version the viewer is using. I'm not sure what you mean by

> injecting a javascript runtime to the underlying Three.JS engine

You can add custom meshes to the scene by using `viewer.impl.scene.add(mesh)`